# Does Grails surround log statements with isSomethingEnabled()

Tags: grails, groovy

As per http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+1.8+release+notes#Groovy18releasenotes-Log groovy does surround log statements with checks like isDebugEnabled() etc.

Does grails do that for the generated code?

For this log call in a grails service:

```
log.debug("competitors errors stage 1: ${failedCarrierRequests}")
```

In the decompiled .class file I see only this:

```
arrayOfCallSite[85].call(log, new GStringImpl(new Object[] { allCompetitorDepartmentsRows.get() }, new String[] { "All competitors: ", "" }));
```

It is unclear whether there is a check for log level behind the scenes or not.

Comment: Maybe decompiling a Groovy class answer this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2.2.2: no.

Grails injects an apache commons Log field into the artefact classes, and the log4j plugin marries that to a log4j Logger.

However, in your example you pass a `GString` as the only parameter. Since they are lazy-transformed to Java `Strings`, the log4j logger would hit it's own internal debug enabled check and skip the `toString()` call.

If you do something expensive like parameter building, however, and you're concerned about the wasted cycles, you must call `isDebugEnabled()` yourself:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("Some string concatenation with a slow method: " + slowMethod())
}
```

I should point out that this contrived example could be converted to use `GString` to save the debug check:

```
log.debug "GString with lazily initialized slow method call: ${slowMethod()}"
```

There was some discussion awhile back on the grails-user mailing list about adding an AST transformation to add the checks, but it didn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Okay response that GStrings are lazy loaded doesn't seems to hold up against my testing.

I have created a test to basically log something four different ways, and it does appear to evaluate any logging statement GString.

Here is my test file GIST:  https://gist.github.com/tgsoverly/34f9a56287291297777b

The test fails for the GString and the method **IS** called when in the log statement.

It would also not be something the groovy people say should be the case according to their template section: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString